# adicionar um elemento em um array sendo ele uma variável e iterar esse array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, for, lógica

Estou criando um editor de texto e para que eu consiga editar cada palavra, eu gostaria de colocar estas palavras em um array, depois disto editar cada elemento do array.

1. Consegui capturar os elementos do HTML e guardar em uma variável.
2. Consegui fazer a lógica para separar as palavras a cada espaçamento em uma variável
3. **Não consegui** fazer o valor desta variável ser um elemento do array e continuar inserindo palavras (valores das variáveis) neste array.
   HTML

````
    var word = document.getElementById("papermain");
    var transformWord = word.value.toString();
    
    /* */
    /* pegando o texto dentro da text area e transformando tudo em string, a final é apenas um editor de texto não realiza funções matématicas como um execel
    por exemplo */
    var separateWord = transformWord.includes(' '); // a função nativa includes procura o que está dentro de (' ') no caso espaçamento para separar as palavras
    myText = [];
    
    if (separateWord == true) {  // a função retorna verdadeiro ou falso, então se tiver espaço faz a instrução.
        
        word = transformWord;
        for (var i = 0, myText; myText = myText[i]; i++) {
            myText.push(word);
            console.log(myText.length)
        }
        console.log(word);

    } ```
````

Comment: já tentou usar `split`? por exemplo `"isso é um teste".split(" ");` isso vai te retornar um array com cada palavra sendo um elemento do array

Comment: @RicardoPontual não tentei, vou pesquisar e tentar, obrigado pela sugestão logo que eu tentar eu mando outro comentário.

Comment: @RicardoPontual poxa cara acho que é exatamente o que eu precisava, ainda testando mas acredito que era isso mesmo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer transformar uma string em um array onde cada palavra ocupa uma posição.
Você pode usar isso usando a função split do javascript.

[Link do w3schools sobre - Função split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_split)

Exemplo:

```
let texto = "How are you doing today?";
const resultado = texto.split(" ");
console.log(resultado)
```

Resultado: ['How', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today?']

Comment: é exatamente isso, outro cara também tinha me informado, e também percorri o array utilizando o método nativo com o forEach! Obrigado